# Laravel 9 & inertis.js data from amny tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

I think i do a little bad things in my code and need some review/advice if there is a simplier way to same goal.

Below is working code, but i think there are too many DB Queries in single page.

database looks like:

```
devices
    id
    company_id
    serial
    modele_id
    uklad_id
```

my company, modele, uklad tables don't have device_id field

I think there should be way to load data from foreign tables connected on model but how?

```
public function devices()
    {
        return Inertia::render('Devices', [
            'dataForTables' => Device::query()
                ->when(Request::input('search'), function ($query, $search) {
                    $query->where('serial', 'like', "%{$search}%");
                })
                ->paginate(10)
                ->withQueryString()
                // missing method ??
                ->through(function ($data) {
                    //ddd($data);
                    $response = [
                        'id' => $data->id,
                        'company_id' => $data->company_id,
                        'company' => Company::where('id', $data->company_id)
                            ->value('name'),
                        'typ' => Modele::where('id', $data->modele_id)
                            ->value('typ'),
                        'serial' => $data->serial,
                        'modele_id' => $data->modele_id,
                        'modele' => Modele::where('id', $data->modele_id)
                            ->value('model'),
                        'producent' => Modele::where('id', $data->modele_id)
                            ->value('producent'),
                        'uklad_id' => $data->uklad_id,
                        'uklad' => Uklad::where('id', $data->uklad_id)
                            ->value('nazwa'),
                    ];
                    foreach (DeviceLokale::where('device_id', $data->id)->get() as $lokal) {
                        $response['lokal'][] = Lokale::find($lokal->lokale_id);
                    }
                    return $response;
                }),
            'filters' => Request::only(['search']),
        ]);
    }
```

ddd of $data below. i do not see any relations data here, so i probably need to add some method but which one.

```
App\Models\Device {#1352 ▼
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "devices"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  +preventsLazyLoading: false
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
  #attributes: array:7 [▶]
  #original: array:7 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #attributeCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
```

I also find https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#joins

but is seems that ->join() work in oposite direction.

My device model have relations:

```
public function company()
    {
            return $this->belongsTo(Company::class);
    }
public function uklad()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Uklad::class);
    }
public function modele()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Modele::class);
    }
```

Comment: Well ! You can use the `with(['array of relationships'])`

Answer (score 0):

After more testing and documentation searching I found that $data->modele etc. works like on normal Eloquent query (facepalm).

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse